# Get fields with same value in sub select on joined tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, inner-join, subquery

I have run into an issue. It is difficult to explain so I will place the example below:

MY TABLES:

```
region_hotelids
------------------------
EANHotelID  |  RegionID
------------------------
1234           935
2343           935
1234           850

hotel_attributes
------------------------
EANHotelID  |  AttributeID
------------------------
1234           1
1234           2
1234           4
1234           6

2343           1
2343           4
2343           2
2343           9
```

Now I first needed to find all the hotels with the  same attributes:

```
SELECT r.EANHotelID, COUNT(c.EANHotelID) AS cat_count
FROM region_hotelid as r 
INNER JOIN hotel_attributes AS c ON r.EANHotelID = c.EANHotelID
WHERE c.AttributeID IN (1,2) AND r.RegionID = 935
GROUP BY c.EANHotelID
HAVING cat_count = 2
```

This works beautifully and outputs this (finding all the EANHotelIDs containing these two attributeIDs):

```
result
EANHotelID  |  cat_count
---------------------------
1234           2
2343           2
```

Now the issue is, I need to get all the other attribute ids that these two hotels have in common. Which in this example would be only the AttributeID 4. I do not want any AttributeIDS that are not the same (in this example 9 and 6). This is what I came up with adding to the original query:

```
SELECT r.EANHotelID, COUNT(c.EANHotelID) AS cat_count, 
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(c2.AttributeID) as ids 
     FROM hotel_attributes as c2 
     WHERE c2.EANHotelID = r.EANHotelID
     AND c.EANHotelID = r.EANHotelID
     GROUP BY c2.EANHotelID ORDER BY ids ASC ) as similarIds
FROM region_hotelid as r 
INNER JOIN hotel_attributes AS c ON r.EANHotelID = c.EANHotelID
WHERE c.AttributeID IN (9,44) AND r.RegionID = 935
GROUP BY c.EANHotelID
HAVING cat_count = 2
```

But instead of only returning the id I want (4 or all of them - 1,2,4) it is returning all the AttributeIds associated with this EANHotelID:

```
result
EANHotelID  |  cat_count  |  similarIds
----------------------------------------
1234           2            1,2,3,4,6
2343           2            1,2,3,4,9
```

I am completely stumped on how to get past this. Any advice or information would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use another `INNER JOIN` to select only the rows where all hotels have the same attributes. I moved the `WHERE` clause into the `JOIN`s `ON` condition.

See a working [SQL-Fiddle example here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/124a8/7).

Note that your `HAVING COUNT(..)` condition is not performing well. The database engine has to examine each result set after the SELECT to see if your `HAVING` condition matches. I've left that untouched, but i think this should be optimized as well!

```
SELECT 
  ha.*
FROM
  hotel_attributes ha 
INNER JOIN hotel_attributes ha_other
ON
  ha.AttributeID = ha_other.AttributeID
  AND NOT ha.EANHotelID = ha_other.EANHotelID
  AND ha_other.EANHotelID IN ( SELECT r.EANHotelID
    FROM region_hotelids as r 
    INNER JOIN hotel_attributes AS c ON r.EANHotelID = c.EANHotelID
    WHERE c.AttributeID IN (1,2) AND r.RegionID = 935
    GROUP BY c.EANHotelID
    HAVING COUNT(c.EANHotelID) = 2
  )
GROUP BY ha.EANHotelID, ha.AttributeID
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer, but the load time on this is obscene. The tables I put in my example were not complete, for the purpose of this question. It works perfectly, but the main search is for the regionid. This is why I need it to be first above and beyond everything else. There is no way to take my original query and modify it? The first query is used quite often and I nee to simply add a query onto it. Again though thank you so much

Comment: @WhitneySarahRogers If your query is slow, try adding an INDEX for both `(hotel_attributes.EANHotelID, hotel_attributes.AttributeID)`. I'll see if this can be optimized somehow.

Comment: @WhitneySarahRogers, can you provide more example data on SQLFiddle? I can't see why that query might perform slowly, given you have INDEXes on the relevant columns.

Comment: @WhitneySarahRogers the query must be this way round, because your WHERE and HAVING conditions limit the result set to only the attributes 1 and 2. To retrieve the other attributes, you need to re-use the hotel-ids and start another query, which is what i'm doing by moving your query into the ON condition for the JOIN.